# Logo images are not loading on live server

Tags: html, css, slider, webserver

I have a logo slider. it runs perfectly on visual studio but when I upload to server it doesn't load. But it load any other images. images are in png .

```
          <div class="mySlider">
               <div class="slide-item">
               <img src="img/picture8.png"> 
            </div>
  
            <div class="slide-item">
               <img src="img/picture8.png" >
            </div>
  
             <div class="slide-item">
              <img src="img/picture8.png"> 
            </div>
  
             <div class="slide-item">
              <img src="img/picture8.png"> 
            </div>
  
            <div class="slide-item">
              <img src="img/picture8.png"> 
           </div>
  
            <div class="slide-item">
              <img src="img/picture8.png"> 
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share the code on codepen or any other code-sharing portal.